# Extending (Monkey Patching) a Binary Search for Array Class and Syntactic Sugar

Tags: ruby

I've been studying a few searching algorithms and my last problem comes down to binary searching. I watched a few youtube videos to understand the concept and then tried to solve the problem, but keep getting an endless loop error. I've looked through stack overflow, and reddit, and wherever Google would lead me, but I can't quite find a solution that fits my method of coding. Also, please excuse the term 'monkey patching', it's been brought to my attention that the technical term is called 'extending' so the fault lies on my instructors for teaching it to us as 'monkey patching'.

Here's my code:

```
class Array
   def my_bsearch(target)

    return nil if self.empty?

    middle_idx = self.length/2

    left = self.take(middle_idx)
    right = self.drop(middle_idx + 1)

    return middle_idx if self[middle_idx] == target

    until self[middle_idx] == target || self.nil? == nil
      if self[middle_idx] < target
        right.my_bsearch(target)
      elsif self[middle_idx] > target
        left.my_bsearch(target)
      end
    end

  end
end
```

I have a solution, but I don't want to just memorize it-- and I'm having trouble understanding it; as I'm trying to translate it, learn from it, and implement what I'm missing into my own code.

```
class Array
  def my_bsearch(target)
    return nil if size == 0
    mid = size/2

    case self[mid] <=> target
    when 0
      return mid
    when 1
      return self.take(mid).my_bsearch(target)
    else
      search_res = self.drop(mid+1).my_bsearch(target)
      search_res.nil? ? nil : mid + 1 + search_res
    end
  end
end
```

I guess I understand case/when despite not use to using it. I've tried following it with debugger, but I think I'm hung up on what's going on in the ELSE section. The syntactic sugar, while making this obviously more concise than my logic, isn't straight-forward/clean to someone of my ruby literacy level. So, yeah, my ignorance is most of the problem I guess.

Is there someone who is a little more literate, and patient, able to help me break this down into something I can understand a bit better so I can learn from this?

Comment: Regarding formatting, to have a code block stand out you've surrounded it with a series of backticks. That's OK, but the usual practice is to indent your code four spaces. If you like you can write your code with no indent, then select it and click on `{}` above the code box. That will shift your code 4 spaces. To highlight `middle_element` in the text in your answer, surround it with backticks.

Comment: The `return` keword (in two places) in not needed, as the return value of the `case` statement will be the return value of the method. `self` is the implicit receiver of instance methods, so you generally don't need `self.`. You've omitted `self.` in `mid = size/2` but not in `self.take` and `self.drop`.  You can't change `self[mod]` to `[mod]`, but you could write `[].(mid)`, which I do not recommend. The second line under `else` could be `mid + 1 my_besearch unless besearch.nil?`, as `nil` is returned if the `unless` test fails. Some may view this as less clear than what you wrote, however.

Answer (score 1):

First, `take` and `drop` have sufficiently similar interfaces that you don't actually want your `+ 1` for drop.  It will disregard one element in the array if you do.

Next, `self.nil?` will always be `false` (and never `nil`) for instances of this class.  In fact, `.nil?` is a method exactly to avoid having to ever compare against `nil` with `==`.

You want `self.empty?`.  Furthermore, with the exception of setters, in Ruby messages are sent to `self` by default.  In other words, the only time `self.` is a useful prefix is when the message ends in `=` and operates as an lvalue, as in `self.instance_var = 'a constant'`, since without the `self.`, the tokens `instance_var =` would be interpreted as a local variable rather than an instance variable setting.  That's not the case here, so `empty?` will suffice just as well as `self.empty?`

Comment: Hi Tim, 

Thanks for jumping in, it looks like I posted right as you were. I've looked over your suggestions and edited the code in my follow up post. I cleaned up the redundant .nil? == true comparison as well as the self.empty?. I tried self.empty? on the line for return nil if searched_right_side.nil? and it errored out in rspec. So I'm keeping it as .nil? unless you can think of something otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out, and I decided to answer my own post in hopes to help someone else out if they run into this issue.

So, if I have an Array and the target is the middle_element, then it will report middle_element_idx. That's fine. What if the target is less than middle_element? It recursively searches the left-side of the original Array. When it finds it, it reports the left_side_idx. There's no problem with that because elements in an array are sequentially counted left to right. So, it starts at 0 and goes up.

But what if the target is on the right side of the middle element?

Well, searching for the right side is easy. Relatively the same logic as searching left. Done recursively. And it will return a target_idx if it's found on that right side --however that's the target's idx as it was found in the right-side array! So, you need to take that returned target_idx and add 1 to it and the original middle_element_idx. See below:

```
  def my_bsearch(target)

    return nil if self.empty?

    middle_idx = self.length/2
    left = self.take(middle_idx)
    right = self.drop(middle_idx + 1)

      if self[middle_idx] == target
        return middle_idx
      elsif self[middle_idx] > target
        return left.my_bsearch(target)
      else
        searched_right_side = 1 + right.my_bsearch(target)
        return nil if searched_right_side.nil? == true
        return searched_right_side + middle_idx
      end

  end
end
```

Notice how many more lines this solution is? The spaceship operator used in conjunction with case/when and a ternary method will reduce the number of lines significantly.

Based on suggestions/feedback from Tim, I updated it to:

```
  def my_bsearch(target)

    return nil if empty?

    middle_idx = self.length/2
    left = self.take(middle_idx)
    right = self.drop(middle_idx)

      if self[middle_idx] == target
        return middle_idx
      elsif self[middle_idx] > target
        return left.my_bsearch(target)
      else
        searched_right_side = right.my_bsearch(target)
        return nil if searched_right_side.nil?
        return searched_right_side + middle_idx
      end

  end
end
```